# HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID

Tags: solidity, tokens, python, infura, brownie

I'm following this solidity tutorial from Patrick Collins and when running a script:

```
brownie run scripts/1_deploy_token.py --network rinkeby
```

I get this error:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 1
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 2
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 4
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 5
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 7
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 8
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 9
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 1
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 2
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 4
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 5
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 7
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 8
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 9
Erc20TokenProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts\1_deploy_token.py::main'...
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\scripts\1_deploy_token.py", line 10, in main
    our_token = OurToken.deploy(initial_supply, {"from": account})
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    return tx["from"].deploy(
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    gas_price, gas_strategy, gas_iter = self._gas_price(gas_price)
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    return web3.eth.generate_gas_price(), None, None
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    return self._generate_gas_price(transaction_params)
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    return self.gasPriceStrategy(self.web3, transaction_params)
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    return web3.manager.request_blocking(RPC.eth_gasPrice, [])
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    response = self._make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    return request_func(method, params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    raw_response = make_post_request(
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID
```

I've redacted the infura id from the above url, but the id that's showing in the url in the error is different from the one that's in my .env file. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with the values (WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID) provided in your .env file,
check if

- there are any errors in the Key or The value provided
- there are any empty lines in the .env file(if yes, remove them)

Comment: I've done what you've suggested but I'm still getting the same error. I could send you my .env file and the other files associated with the project personally if that helps.